# how to call magento soap webservice in windows form application?

Tags: winforms, soap, magento-1.9

I have soap link like this http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl (it is a magento website), the username password is abc , 123

I just added a service reference at solution explorer the name is ServiceReference1

I created a button (using vs2015, project name is printOrder) as the code is following:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

the app.config is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <configuration>
            <startup> 
                <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
            </startup>
            <system.serviceModel>
                <bindings>
                    <basicHttpBinding>
                        <binding name="Binding" />
                    </basicHttpBinding>
                </bindings>
                <client>
                    <endpoint address="http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/"
                        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding"
                        contract="ServiceReference1.PortType" name="Port" />
                </client>
            </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

So, 
1) how to create a soap client object with username and password? 
2) after created  soap client object, how do i call the web service?

i've searched a lot of topics in google but seems there is small different from my case......

Anyone know how to to that?

The same thing i want to do is

```
$cs = getSesstion();
$result = $cs['client']->salesOrderShipmentInfo($cs['session'], '200001811');

$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'orderIncrementId',
            'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => '100004496')
        )
    )
);
var_dump($cs);
//$result = $cs['client']->salesOrderInfo($cs['session'],'100004496');
//var_dump($result);

function getSesstion() {

    $client = new SoapClient('http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

    $username = 'vtec';
    $apikey= 'Abcd1234';


    $session = $client->login($username, $apikey);
    $cs = array();
    $cs['client'] = $client;
    $cs['session'] = $session;
    return $cs;

}
```

----------------------------answer-----------------------------
with Regie Baquero's help, the right code i found is

```
        ServiceReference1.PortTypeClient client = new ServiceReference1.PortTypeClient();
        string session = client.login("vtec","Abcd1234");

        Console.WriteLine(session);
        //client.(session, "product_stock.list", "qqaz");
        var result = client.salesOrderInfo(session, "145000037");

        //client.endSession(session);
        Console.WriteLine(result.increment_id.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already added your soap service what you need is to declare it in your code something like:

```
`ServiceReference1.Service service variable = new ServiceReference1.Service();`
```

in order for you to access method or function inside the soap service.

Sample code if you have written your soap service in visual studio c# your code should look like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool Password_Verification(string password)
{
      if(password=="12345")
    {
        return true;
     }
}
```

you can access it using

```
        `ServiceReference1.Service service variable = new ServiceReference1.Service();`
             bool verify = service variable.Password_Verification("12345");
```

Same goes with wsdl file. you just need to know what function/method is implemented in that soap service.

.........................

Comment: https://s26.postimg.org/5hz6xjg09/soap.png can't create object using ServiceReference1

Comment: service variable is just an illustration to make it readable . variable should have no spaces.

Comment: Do you have a live wsdl file for me to test?

Comment: ServiceReference1.Service service = new ServiceReference1.Service(); , .Service is maked red underline

Comment: may i see how you added your service?

Comment: right click reference->add service reference
https://s26.postimg.org/uqk0r7ky1/soap3.png

Comment: i have written a blog for this. you might want to check this out. 
http://regiebaquero-001-site1.ftempurl.com/Home/Consume_Webservice

Comment: I'm not familiar of what method this soap service offer. but you can access it using this code

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.PortTypeClient s = new ServiceReference1.PortTypeClient();
            s.catalogCategoryAssignedProducts("session idd sds ",1);
        }

Comment: this is a method from your wsdl with patameter
     `ServiceReference1.customerCustomerEntityToCreate create = new 
       ServiceReference1.customerCustomerEntityToCreate(); `

            `create.customer_id = 1;
            create.email = "@gmail.com";
            create.password = "123";
            create.firstname = "abc"; `

Comment: As i have read your soap service password are embedded within every transaction like  ServiceReference1.customerCustomerEntityToCreate.
i think you just need to include it in every method you call.